# check the records that whether includes date format or not

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column contains strings like `13.04.2021 / CC 45,00` , `CCC 54,43 3.05.2021` or null records. and I want to trim dates and I need only others. For example we take `13.04.2021 / CC 45,00` records. I need only `CC 45,00` string.

Comment: Is there any pattern to get the sub-string? Do you need the string after `/`? What should 2nd string generate?

Comment: I am afraid i have no pattern for sub string. I need only trim dates. I dont need / string.

Comment: Ok. So dose second string should return only `CCC 54,43`?

Comment: but i am sure that all dates records include two '.' . For example it is not 13/04/2021, it is 13.04.2021.

Comment: yes, second one should return only [CCC 54,43].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to remove the dates from your strings and they are only in the pattern of `dd.mm.yyyy`, You can try below pattern -

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(STR, '(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4})', '')
  FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=237b7cb2036b6ecc1f809e4128378b4b)

Comment: Dots should be escaped also. Otherwise it would remove, for example, large numbers (with 8 to 10 symbols)